# regular expression div tags

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ I am trying to eliminate all of the spaces in a div tag except for a space between the comma and the last name.

Input:

```
<div class="n"> Joe ,   Williams    </div>
```

Output:

```
Example = "<div class="n">Joe, Williams</div>"
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Which language are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I copied the text from an excel spreadsheet. I just need to modify so I can paste it into a website.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `replace`, be sure to mark `regular expression`or `Regexp`.

This should be your `search` field: `<div class="([\w -]+)">[ ]+([A-Za-z]+)[ ,]+([A-Za-Z]+)[ ]*</div>`

And this should be your `replace by` field: `<div class="$1">$2, $3</div>`

Comment: @mustyg123 I don't know if you wish to have the `Example = ...` included in the output so if this is the case, here you go: `Example = "<div class="$1">$2, $3</div>"`

Comment: Hmm Hello, thank you for you help. But that didn't seem to work for me.